# JSF ResourceBundle DYnamic calling from bean

Tags: jsf-2, internationalization, javabeans, resourcebundle

On my JSF pages, I can easily call my resource bundle using something like this

```
#{msg.formatwidth}
```

However, I also want to call my resourceBundle with my current choosen language in my backbean. The standard netbeans generated code for that is

```
java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle("resource/messages_en").getString("dbupdate")
```

but that will only get it in english eventhough my language is set ti french or ducth. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [the `getBundle()` method which takes a locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29).

```
String basename = "resource/messages";
Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(basename, locale);
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the current locale as BalusC pointed out. However you should configure the supported-locale in your faces-context.xml as well.